# SVG inside HTML table behavior with box-sizing and borders

Tags: html, css, svg, html-table

I was experimenting with SVGs inside HTML table cells. All HTML elements have set `box-sizing` to `border-box`, so the border sizes are included in the elements size.

Unfortunately it seems like cell contents like text behave differently to SVGs where the border sizes are not (or only partly) included in the cell height (based on what browser you use).

I have set up a fiddle with the below code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k6pLaf27/4/)

#### Table with SVG

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

tr {
  height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="first">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="second">
    <td>4</td>
    <td style="border-top: 1px solid red; border-bottom: 1px solid blue">5</td>
    <td style="padding: 0; border-top: 1px solid red; border-bottom: 1px solid blue">
      <svg style="display: block" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
        <circle cx="11" cy="11" r="10" stroke="green" stroke-width="1" fill="yellow" />
      </svg>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="third">
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr class="first">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="second">
    <td>4</td>
    <td style="border-top: 1px solid red; border-bottom: 1px solid blue">5</td>
    <td style="padding: 0; border-top: 1px solid red; border-bottom: 1px solid blue">
      6
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="third">
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You'll see that in Chrome the second row with the SVG is higher (23px) than the second row without SVG.
In Firefox the SVG cell size is not reduced at all even when the SVG cell does only have one border on top or bottom.
IE and Edge seem to do it, even though I found more complex table examples where is would not work somehow.

My question is if in Chrome it's how it is supposed to work (Could not find a specification for that) or if it's wrong.